# Как сделать "защиту от дурака"? (Игра "Поле чудес")

Tags: java

Необходимо сделать "защиту от дурака", (чтобы пользователь мог ввести только слово длинной загаданного или только один символ + без пробелов). Желательно без регулярных выражений(ещё не проходили). Помогите, пожалуйста.)

```
package javaapplication1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Play round1 = new Play();
        round1.PlayTheGame();
    }

}

class Play {

    String ch;
    char chr;

    void PlayTheGame() {
        String text = "chocolate";
        StringBuilder text2 = new StringBuilder(text);
        int rez = 0;
        int temp = 0;
        boolean[] mask = new boolean[text.length()];
        for (boolean b : mask) {
            b = false;
        }

        while (temp != text.length()) {

            System.out.println("Key in one character or your guess word"+"("+text.length()+" letters)"+": ");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);


            ch = scanner.next();
            if ((ch.length()!=1)||(ch.length()!=text.length())) { // таким способом не получается
                System.out.println("You entered incorrect data!");
                break;
            }
            chr  = ch.charAt(0);
            rez = rez + 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
                if ((ch.equals(text))) {
                    temp = text.length();
                    System.out.print(text);
                    break;

                }
                if (chr == text.charAt(i)) {
                    mask[i] = true;
                    temp = temp + 1;
                }

                if (mask[i] == true) {
                    System.out.print(text.charAt(i));
                } else {
                    System.out.print("_");
                }

            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("rezult = " + rez);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну если юзер ввел что то неправильно, попросите его ввести это заново и все дела.

Answer (score 2):

Вкратце, ответ на ваш вопрос:

```
    if (ch.contains(" ") 
         || (ch.toCharArray().length!=text.toCharArray().length && ch.toCharArray().length!=1)) { 
            System.out.println("You entered incorrect data!");
            break;             //!!!!!!тогда игра заканчивается, надо убрать чтобы мы могли после выдачи ошибки продолжить
    }
```

Но у вас есть и другие ошибки:

1. например цикл игры закончится если не убрать `break`.
   уберите его и поставьте `else`, включив в него все оставшиеся проверки в цикле ввода.
2. `ch = scanner.next();` переходит к следующей букве а нам надо к строке. Используйте `nextLine()`.
3. вы перепутали `rez = rez + 1` и `temp = temp + 1`. просто переставьте их местами. Иначе счет (`rez`) не увеличится при верной букве, а цикл сократится ибо увеличена циклическая переменная (`temp`).

Возможно есть еще какие то ошибки и я забыл их сюда вписать, но в результате отредактированный, рабочий код будет таким:

```
public class JavaApplication1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Play round1 = new Play();
        round1.PlayTheGame();
    }

}

class Play {

String ch;
char chr;

void PlayTheGame() {
    String text = "chocolate";
    StringBuilder text2 = new StringBuilder(text);
    int rez = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    boolean[] mask = new boolean[text.length()];
    for (boolean b : mask) {
        b = false;
    }

    while (temp != text.toCharArray().length) {

        System.out.println("Key in one character or your guess word" + "(" + text.length() + " letters)" + ": ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);


        ch = scanner.next(); //вот тут ошибка! нужно использовать nextLine

        if (ch.contains(" ") || (ch.toCharArray().length != text.toCharArray().length && ch.toCharArray().length != 1)) { 
            System.out.println("You entered incorrect data!");
        } else {   //ставим стобы цикл продолжался после некорректного ввода

            chr = ch.charAt(0);
            temp = temp + 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
                if ((ch.equals(text))) {
                    temp = text.length();
                    System.out.print(text);
                    break;

                }
                if (chr==text.charAt(i)) {
                    mask[i] = true;
                    rez = rez + 1;
                }

                if (mask[i]) {
                    System.out.print(text.charAt(i));
                } else {
                    System.out.print("_");
                }

            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("rezult = " + rez);
        }
    }
}
}
```